# Map property using OwnsOne method in EF Core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate EF 6 project to EF Core 2.0. 
I would like to streess out that I am not allowed to change anything in database structure - must be exactly the same as for EF 6 project.

I have the foloowing entities:

```
abstract class Vehicle { ... }

abstract class Car : Vehicle 
{ 
    public Dimension Dimensions { get; set; } 
}

class Audi : Car { ... }

class Mazda : Car { ... }

class Dimension
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

Table mappings as follows:

```
public VehicleMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Vehicle> entityBuilder)
{
    entityBuilder.ToTable("Vehicles");
    entityBuilder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
    entityBuilder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type").HasValue<Truck>(nameof(Truck));
}

public CarMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Car> entityBuilder)
{
    entityBuilder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
        .HasValue<Mazda>(nameof(Mazda))
        .HasValue<Audi>(nameof(Audi));

    **entityBuilder.OwnsOne(_ => _.Dimensions);**
}
```

The problem I have is about `Dimensions` property defined in `Car` abstract class. I would like to map it using `OwnsOne` method to have all its class properties defined in the same table.

I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot use table 'Vehicles' for entity type 'Car.Dimensions#Dimension'
>   since it has a relationship to a derived entity type 'Car'. Either
>   point the relationship to the base type 'Vehicle' or map
>   'Car.Dimensions#Dimension' to a different table.

Any idea how to solve it in EF Core 2.0?

Comment: i am having the same problem... Seems like Entity Framework Core 2.0 not support this.

Answer (score 0):

> The `Dimension` known as [ValueObject](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html). The best practice for this type of objects is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects).

To implement this objects in your context first you should define it in base table, since when you create database with this configuration you have just one table with the name of `Vehicles` and discriminator column with the name of `Type`.

As the error say:

> Either point the relationship to the base type 'Vehicle'

we should define `Dimension` in base class.

```
abstract class Vehicle 
{
    public Dimension Dimensions { get; private set; } 
}
```

Table mappings:

```
public VehicleMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Vehicle> entityBuilder)
{
    entityBuilder.ToTable("Vehicles");
    entityBuilder.HasKey(_ => _.Id);
    entityBuilder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type").HasValue<Truck>(nameof(Truck));
    // Here
    entityBuilder.OwnsOne(p => p.Dimensions);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a base ConfigurationBuilder for your Car class. Than you can make a configuration class (http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/move-configurations-to-seperate-class-in-code-first.aspx)

Than you can do something like this:

```
public class CarConfiguration<TBase> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBase>
    where TBase : class, Car
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBase> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Dimensions);
    }
}
```

After that you can use a configurationClass that derives from CarConfiguration foreach item that derives from car e.g.

```
public class AudiConfiguration : CarConfiguration<Audi>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Audi> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder); //call this to use configuration from Car

        builder.....
    }
}
```